# View with parameter IN

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I'm creating a view in which I have a where with an in clause and I want it to be a parameter. Unfortunately views can't be created with parameters, so I tried replacing it with functions, but functions only return a string.

Is there a way to create a view that accepts multiple options? example:

```
SELECT name, surname from people WHERE name in (@names)
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5

Comment: What is the value you're trying to pass with `@names`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a *User-defined variable (UDF)* through a `IN` clause, but you could make a *Dynamic SQL Statement* like this:

**Example table:**

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  fName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  lName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  pwd varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  rol varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Values:**

```
insert into test.user(id,fName,lName,pwd,rol)VALUES(1,'oNare', 'Test', '123ka21312', NULL);
insert into test.user(id,fName,lName,pwd,rol)VALUES(2,'Another','Test',1,1);
insert into test.user(id,fName,lName,pwd,rol)VALUES(3,'Other','Test',1,1);
```

**Checking information:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test.user;
+----+---------+-------+------------+------+
| id | fName   | lName | pwd        | rol  |
+----+---------+-------+------------+------+
|  1 | oNare   | Test  | 123ka21312 | NULL |
|  2 | Another | Test  | 1          | 1    |
|  3 | Other   | Test  | 1          | 1    |
+----+---------+-------+------------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Dynamic SQL with [PREPARED statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):**

```
SET @names="'oNare','Another'";
SET @query=CONCAT("SELECT
                            fName,
                            lName
                        FROM test.user
                        WHERE fName IN (",@names,")");
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

#Test
mysql> SET @names="'oNare','Another'";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @query=CONCAT("SELECT
    "> fName,
    "> lName
    "> FROM test.user
    "> WHERE fName IN (",@names,")");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+---------+-------+
| fName   | lName |
+---------+-------+
| oNare   | Test  |
| Another | Test  |
+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 3):

oNare's answer shows the principle way to achieve this. (He gets a +1 !!!)

He set the variable `@names` as follows:

```
SET @names="'oNare','Another'";
```

Then, his algorithm worked perfectly.

## SUGGESTION

Instead of putting single quotes in `@names`, do it without the single quotes.

Do the delimiting before processing the query with this

```
SET @names='oNare,Another';
SET @names=CONCAT('''',REPLACE(REPLACE(@names,'''',''''''),',',''','''),'''');
```

What does `@names` look like now ???

```
mysql> SELECT @names;
+-------------------+
| @names            |
+-------------------+
| 'oNare','Another' |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I loaded his sample data and tried it out

```
mysql> SET @names='oNare,Another';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @names=CONCAT('''',REPLACE(REPLACE(@namelist,'''',''''''),',',''','''),'''');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @names;
+-------------------+
| @names            |
+-------------------+
| 'oNare','Another' |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET @query=CONCAT("SELECT
    ">                             fName,
    ">                             lName
    ">                         FROM user
    ">                         WHERE fName IN (",@names,")");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
+---------+-------+
| fName   | lName |
+---------+-------+
| oNare   | Test  |
| Another | Test  |
+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: The good about this is that you can't run 2 queries inside the same `PREPARED statement` and this avoid *SQL Injections* like this: `SET @names="1); delete from test.user;(1";`. Btw +1 for the `REPLACE` trick, good one.

Comment: @oNare You are right about that : http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: No problem. My answer was just Chipotle Sauce on his Answer.